# Why does Mikoto attack Touma?

Tags: a-certain-magical-index

In the first episode of *To Aru Majutsu no Index*, Misaka attacks Touma with her Railgun, but she deliberately misses him. After that she attacks him with her usual lighting attack but he nullifies it with his power. But why did Mikoto attack him? It's so unlike her to attack somebody that innocent. (Yes, she does always attack some people, but they usually pick a fight with her first.)

Comment: From the narration of the light novel, it implicitly states that they've crossed path with one another sporadically about a month (which ultimately leads to the confrontation that causes a city-wide blackout). *A Certain Scientific Railgun,* gives a more complete chronicle of how they first met in early June (before the start of the Index).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two have met before Index, in *Toaru Kagaku no Rērugan (A Certain Scientific Railgun)* Misaka encountered Touma and his ability to nullify her attack with his Imagine Breaker in his right hand. When Misaka asked how Touma did it he says he doesn't know yet Misaka doesn't believe him.

This annoyed Misaka because she's one of the strongest Espers in the city (one of only a handful of Level 5's) and she's proud of it, Touma is a "Level 0" so he shouldn't be any match for Misaka however she can't win against thanks to Touma's Imagine Breaker and without knowing how it works Misaka can't accept that she is bested by him.

In Index they already know one another, it's just that after Episode 6 of the Index Anime Touma acts as if he doesn't know her because his memory was wiped out from a feather that remained after the effects of St. George's Sanctuary when Index was in Johann's Pen Mode.

Comment: but Misaka seems surprise to see her attack didn't work?

Comment: Like Memor-X explained, it's because she doesn't know about Touma's imagine breaker. All of her adversaries were able to be zapped up until this point.

Also, she probably attacks him because she knows it won't be effective. Although this is probably more due to her being a "tsundere."

Comment: @ShinobuOshino i think i remember Misaka trying something new on Touma with her actual attack and was surprised that with no effort it was still ineffective on Touma. what i do know is that Touma and Misaka already fought in Railgun and Misaka was persistent in having a rematch and it's the reason why she's already familiar with him in Index

Comment: @Frosteeze she knows he's got some weird ability to stop her attacks despite being a Level 0, she just doesn't know how it works. i can't remember if she knows it's called the Imagine Breaker or not

Comment: Uh.. I need to re watch Railgun because I don't remember it happening there

Comment: @ShinobuOshino i read the Railgun Manga up to just after Misaka's fist encounter with Accelerator before ever seeing Index, if my memory serves me right Touma comes to Misaka's aid from a bunch of thugs not knowing who Misaka is and that she could handle herself, Misaka explains she's one of the top espers and goes to prove it but Touma blocks it. someone correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @Memor-X This explanation is a little off. Touma only loses his memory in ep06 of Index, which is chronologically after ep01. Touma and Misaka are acquainted for around a month before he loses his memory, during which time Misaka has attacked him a number of times (cf. Railgun ep02), so by the time Index ep01 rolls around, they're both sort of used to Misaka trying and failing to zap him.

Comment: @senshin when you say "ep06 of Index, which is chronologically after ep01", by ep01 you mean the first episode of the railgun anime?

Comment: @Memor-X No, I mean the first episode of Index.

Comment: @Frosteeze: "Thundere", you mean. :)

Answer (score 0):

The actual reason behind Misaka's attacks is quite simple. It is played for pure comedic purposes. Tsunderes act out of character near their crushes - a common trope found in anime.
Basically, Misaka was worried about how a level 0 like Touma could deflect her attacks. She thought that she must be missing something, and the same tactic might be used against her by criminals. Attacking Touma again and again would probably help her realise her probable 'weakness' and whatever strategy he is using (since he never disclosed the truth initially). 
Since they became closer, Touma became one upon whom Misaka would vent her emotional frustration, and ends up fighting him. It does not help very much then, when Touma teases her in the process, making her feel more insecure. 
The last reason, from Touma's perspective, is bad luck. To Aru Majutsu no Index confirmed that he was BORN to be misunderstood.